# WPF control retained in memory due to DispatcherTimer EventHandler

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, dispatchertimer

Yo

One of my WPF control is retained in memory due to one of its private member. The incriminate member is a DispatcherTimer and the retention is because of the Tick event handler. (This leak was detected with help of the tool ANTS Memory Profiler)

Obviously, I set/remove the handler on load/unload. And the control is unloaded...

```
void TransportControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (m_playheadTimer == null)
  {
    m_playheadTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    m_playheadTimer.Tick += PlayheadTimer_Tick;
    m_playheadTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
  }
}

void TransportControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (m_playheadTimer != null)
  {
    if (m_playheadTimer.IsEnabled)
      m_playheadTimer.Stop();

    m_playheadTimer.Tick -= PlayheadTimer_Tick;
  }
}
```

But still I'm stuck with that trouble (the same as my control is stuck in memory).
Any ideas, THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at weak event pattern. It is not an exactly easy topic though.

Comment: Thank you very much CommanderZ, you made my day! The tip was exactly what I was searching off. After implementation of a DispatcherTimerWeakEvent my control is removed from the memory.Cheers